# Use Meteor authentication on a seperate(ish) JSON web service to postgresql data

Tags: json, postgresql, reactjs, express, meteor

Background: I'm using meteor with react to primarily build an IOS and andriod app. It's been about 10 years since I last wrote a web up using MS SQL, classic asp and asp.net, but I have since learned quite a bit of nodeJS and some react.

The app I am building is perfect for a relational database backend which I've built in postgres. Having queries with 4+ joins in I can't bare to try and make it work in MongoDB - even with the schema modules I don't want to write my own nested joins, and operate without transactions or having to heavily denomalise data.

Anway, I have written a simple nodeJS JSON API to query postgres and call it stright from react component on my meteor client. When running the meteor site on localhost, I want the react client side to call localhost:3000/data/xList and only get the JSON back if user is already authorised on meteor.

My question is, how can I use meteor authentication/session/token to control access to the JSON APIs, and return pure JSON on a special URL. So far I have tried the below (psudo in places) in server/main.js

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp'; //does  request response etc
import ConnectRoute from 'connect-route'; //same as ExpressJS router
Meteor.startup(() => {
}

function onRoute(req, res, next) {
  const dataQuery = req.params.token;
  if (dataQuery == 'xList' and userIsAuthorised) { 
    JSON_data = getJasonFromPostgresQuery('xList', userID);
    //try and abort all meteor stuff, and just send JSON back
    res.send(JSON_data); //this isn't a method of res though- I was hoping is was the same as the res.send in expressJS?
    res.end;
  }
}

const middleware = ConnectRoute(function(router) {
 //takes incoming http request - if matches /:anything then calls function
router.get('/data/:token', onRoute); //calls function onRoute
});

WebApp.connectHandlers.use(middleware);
```

So that's a bit pseudo, but you get the idea. The router bit seems to work, and the postgreQuesry works. What i don't know is

1) in this context how to check is user is authorised by meteor (ie login in) - this needs to be secure.

2) once auth is check, to send nothing but pure JSON back - assume I have to change headers and content type to JSON - how do i do that too?

for (more) completeness this is my react component fetch, which works with no security when going direct to a sperate (not meteor) nodeJS app.

```
componentWillMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/data/xList')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
        this.setState({ Offers: json.Offers });
        console.log(json);
    });
}
```

I hope that makes sense, many thanks in advance! PS I'm planning to add in meteor facebook integration soon after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, answering my own question. This was quite tricky so I hope this helps someone else. 
Firstly, to setup a JSON web service with-in meteor I user RESTIVUS npm module (meteor add nimble:restivus). Which has good documentation. This allows you to attach a function/code block to GET/POST etc at a specific path/route. eg http://localhost:3000/api/myJSONrequest/myParams.
Secondly, the really confusing bit was handling the async nature of querying the postgres database (using postgres npm moudule pg). This is because it's a few call back nested, AND METEOR Fibre appraoch doesn't allow for async calls, so won't wait for the postgres to return. To get around this I used the Futures approach from fibres/futures module. If I'm honest I don't currently understand it well enough to explain how it works, but here is my code.

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
// code to run on server at startup
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  // Global API configuration
  var Api = new Restivus({
  useDefaultAuth: true,
  prettyJson: true
});

Api.addRoute('offers/:param', { //executes for localhost:3000/api/offers/123
  authRequired: false //here is the meteor auth - set to true to protect ajax call
}, {
    get: function () {
      var getQueryData;
      getQueryData =  () => {
        var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
        var fut;
        fut = new Future;
        var temp = 'no data retrieved';
        var pg = require('pg');
        var conString = "postgres://postgres:xx@localhost:5432/databasex";
        var client = new pg.Client(conString);
        var content = [];
        client.connect();
        var sSQL = "";
        sSQL = sSQL + "SELECT * from Offers";
        var query = client.query(sSQL);
         var data = [];
        query.on('row', function (row) {
          data.push(row); //called once for each row returned
        });
        query.on('end', () => { //called when all rows returned
          client.end();
          temp = '{"Offers":' + JSON.stringify(data) + '}';
          //console.log(temp);
          this.response.write(temp); //restivus response - write JSON
          this.done();//finilise the content
          fut["return"](null);//not sure why this is needed but it works
        return fut.wait();
      }
      return {
      status: 'success',
      data: getQueryData()
    };
    }
  });
}
});
```

lastly, for completeness here is the clientside code, in a react component that uses fetch to call the API. The important bit is that it gets the logged on meteor users id and auth token and adds it to the request headers. This then works when you specify auth is required to get the json content back from the server.

```
  componentWillMount() {
    myHeaders = new Headers({
        "X-User-Id": Accounts.userId(), //adds current meteor userId to head
        "X-Auth-Token": Accounts._storedLoginToken() //add meteor auth token
    });
    var myInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'none'
    };
    fetch('/api/offer/' + this.props.params.id, myInit)
        .then(this.handleErrors)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({ Offer: json.Offer });
            console.log(this.state.Offer[0].name);
            this.render();
        });
}
```